# Icon in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add an icon to my bootstrap code but the code I have added:

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Create Client</a></li>
```

Works on Rails but not on ASP. The link is there without the icon. Is this correct for ASP?

My View as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>@ViewData("Title")</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style type="text/css">
          body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
          }
        </style>
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Courtenay's Laundry</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                  <li class="active"><a href="/Index">Home</a></li>

                <!-- Dropdown menu Service -->  
                <li class="dropdown" id="menu1">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1">
                      Service
                      <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                    <!-- Dropdown menu Clients --> 
                    <li class="dropdown" id="menu2">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu2">
                          Customers
                          <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Create Customer</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Modify Customer</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Delete Customer</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">View Loyalty</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Manually Change Loyalty</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Notify Client</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>

                    <!-- Dropdown menu Management --> 
                    <li class="dropdown" id="menu3">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu3">
                          Management
                          <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>

                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Reporting</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="well sidebar-nav">

            <!--Sidebar content-->
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">Service Links</li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-book icon-white"></i>Book Job</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-book"></i>Book Out Job</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-random"></i>Station Transfer</a></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Client Quick Links</li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Create Client</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-share"></i>Notifications</a></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Reporting</li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-file"></i>Reporting</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-cog"></i>Settings</a></li>
            </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            @RenderBody()      
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-transition.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-alert.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/bootstrap-modal.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-scrollspy.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-tab.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-tooltip.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-popover.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-button.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-collapse.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-carousel.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have:

```
bootstrap-dropdown.js
bootstrap.js
bootstrap.min.js
```

In my script folder

Comment: Then again - check in your browser if all resources can be found. If not - change your url's to the appropriate paths!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have included the bootstrap stylesheets? You can check with your browsers console if any files couldn't be loaded or such. Shouldn't make any difference what server-side language you are using here. Otherwise - check the generated code and post it. I use ASP.Net MVC all the time with Bootstrap, and no issues there - just make sure that your paths are correct (I have a feeling you have a /bootstrap folder in your Contents folder, and you're not referencing to it correctly)!

Here's a simple ASP.NET MVC3 'boilerplate'-ish project. So you can get started really easily. http://wearereasonablepeople.com/APSMVC3BootstrapBoilerplate.zip

Please note: there's no fancy buildscripts in here, it doesn't even include the LESS files, but nonetheLESS it might help you to get started.

Comment: The view seems ok, but as I cannot see the rest of your project, I cannot judge whether your paths are really really correct :) What browser are you using? With Chrome, Safari and Firefox you'll be able to see if all resources could be loaded.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial or anything to follow with regards to installing bootstrap? I just installed it manually with drag and drop but I have a feeling this is not correct. With ruby its just a gem install. Im using chrome on my mac

Comment: ..and did you copy all the bootstrap-assets (the sprites as well)? Because maybe you referenced to the correct CSS, but the CSS tries to load the sprites (PNG). Try and validate the paths there as well.

Comment: Dragging and dropping can work just fine. I'll make you a small 'boilerplate' which you can use. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks so much a boiler plate would be awesome! I did copy the sprites but I think you may be right about the referencing - where would I find the sprite refs.

Comment: Working! You where correct about my refs in CSS. Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries, here's your boilerplate :) http://wearereasonablepeople.com/APSMVC3BootstrapBoilerplate.zip